Code Coverage on Platform and Change Events on External Object
I am getting 0% code coverage on a test class for a platform event/change event apex trigger to trigger from an external object.  In the sandbox, the code coverage is 100% but when I try to push it to Prod it won't do it.  Can anyone shed any light on what I might be doing wrong?  Here is my code:
Apex Trigger:
trigger Partner_Quote_PlatformEvent on Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent (after insert) {
    PartnerQuoteChangeEventHandler.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
}

Apex Change Event Handler:
public class PartnerQuoteChangeEventHandler {
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent> changeEvents) {
        List<Partner_Quotes__e> events = new List<Partner_Quotes__e>();
        for (Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent record : changeEvents) {
            Decimal recommendedPlanPrice = (Decimal)record.get('recommendedPlanPrice__c');
            if (recommendedPlanPrice != null && recommendedPlanPrice >= 1000) {
                Partner_Quotes__e event = new Partner_Quotes__e();
                event.emailAddress__c = (String)record.get('emailAddress__c');
                event.id__c = (Id)record.get('Id');
                event.policyNumber__c = (String)record.get('policyNumber__c');
                event.purchaseEmailAddress__c = (String)record.get('purchaseEmailAddress__c');
                event.recommendedPlanPrice__c = recommendedPlanPrice;
                events.add(event);
            }
        }
        if (!events.isEmpty()) {
            EventBus.publish(events);
        }
    }
}

Apex Test Class:
@isTest
public class TestPartnerQuoteChangeEventHandler {

    @isTest
    static void testHandleAfterInsert() {
        // Create mock ChangeEvent records
        List<Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent> mockChangeEvents = new List<Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent>();

        // Create a high price change event
        Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent highPriceChangeEvent = (Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent)Type.forName('Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent').newInstance();
        highPriceChangeEvent.put('emailAddress__c', 'test@example.com');
        highPriceChangeEvent.put('policyNumber__c', 'PN123456');
        highPriceChangeEvent.put('purchaseEmailAddress__c', 'purchase@example.com');
        highPriceChangeEvent.put('recommendedPlanPrice__c', 1500);
        highPriceChangeEvent.put('Id', '001000000000000AAA');
        mockChangeEvents.add(highPriceChangeEvent);

        // Create a low price change event
        Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent lowPriceChangeEvent = (Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent)Type.forName('Partner_Quote__ChangeEvent').newInstance();
        lowPriceChangeEvent.put('emailAddress__c', 'lowprice@example.com');
        lowPriceChangeEvent.put('policyNumber__c', 'PN654321');
        lowPriceChangeEvent.put('purchaseEmailAddress__c', 'purchase@example.com');
        lowPriceChangeEvent.put('recommendedPlanPrice__c', 500);
        lowPriceChangeEvent.put('Id', '001000000000001AAA');
        mockChangeEvents.add(lowPriceChangeEvent);

        Test.startTest();
        // Invoke the trigger by calling the handler directly
        PartnerQuoteChangeEventHandler.handleAfterInsert(mockChangeEvents);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Since direct verification of platform events is not possible,
        // we assume the success of the publish call as the verification.
    }
}

Thanks!

Have you tried triggering a change so that the trigger code is used rather than calling the method directly?

The trigger will get 0% coverage as there are no database events. You will need to insert/publish records into the object. You may try something like this https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/test-the-change-event-trigger
